# How to hide html video controls for Safari Mobile

Tags: html, css, reactjs, video, safari

I am currently using a video as a background for my website, it works perfectly in my chrome browser, but when I use safari- it shows the video controls for the video in the background. Is there any way to hide these controls or maybe just a better way to have the video in the background?

here's my code for the background video

HTML

```
<video id = 'home-bg' src = {require('../assets/leojaden-video-bg-2.mp4')} muted loop autoPlay playsinline/>
```

CSS

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#home-bg{
    position: absolute;
    filter: brightness(80%);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: -1;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls {
    display: none;
}
```

I am using reactjs for this website, so a react friendly solution would be helpful! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the controls by not adding the controls attribute to the video element.

```
<video autoplay playsinline></video>
```